# Cellular Immunity Response

Tags: homework, immunity

What response of cellular immunity would appear after complementary protein activation to keep pathogenic bacteria away from our body?

Notes: I do appreciate your explanation. Though I am facing multiple choices:

(a) wrapping the bacteria cell (b) immobilize the bacteria cell (c)    destroying the bacteria cell by enzyme (d) creating pores on the bacteria cell

The key answer is (c) but then I do not know what enzymes make this happens. Any Idea?

Comment: Your first sentence is not really a question. You want to know which mechanism of the complement is respsonsible for this protection? If so, can you please re-phrase it?

Comment: Does that has anything to do with your topic? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_system Then, maybe, you are looking for this mechanism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_membrane_attack_complex

Comment: @aandreev so.. option (d) is actually correct then, am I getting this wrong?

Comment: that is for you to decide

Comment: The complement does d.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can simply find on Wikipedia, the cellular immunity, or Cell-mediated immunity,

> is an immune response that does not involve antibodies, but rather
>   involves the activation of phagocytes, antigen-specific cytotoxic
>   T-lymphocytes, and the release of various cytokines in response to an
>   antigen.

The answer (c) (destroying the bacteria cell by enzyme) refers to the [phagocytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phagocyte), cells that contain many enzymes, like lysozymes. Those funny enzyme can destroy the bacteria cell's wall.

Actually, I think that the answer (d) could be right, but it's not complete. In fact not every enzymes works on the cell's wall!

Answer (score 1):

After opsonization the antigen goes through phagocytosis or the complement system destroys it. The complement is a cascade of reactions, which at the end creates a hole (many holes) on the membrane of bacteria which causes lysis. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_membrane_attack_complex

So the right answer is d.) in your case.